# status of Invariant subspace problem on Krein Space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, hilbert-spaces

What is the status of Invariant subspace problem on [Krein Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krein_space)? What sort of developments have taken place in this area.